# Ngrok with Cloudflare domain

Tags: ssl, cloudflare, ngrok, tunneling

I have purchased `ngrok pro` plan to use whitelabeled domains through cloudflare. But having trouble configuring end to end SSL encryption.

1. React app is running on localhost (http://localhost:3000).
2. created a domain (app.example.com) in ngrok.
3. added CNAME record for xxx.ngrok.io url in cloudflare for app.example.com.
4. SSL is enabled in cloudflare
5. https://app.example.com gives HTTP 520 error on cloudflare

cloudflare has universal certificate on *.example.com domain.

Is there anyway i can have  https://app.example.com resolves to https://localhost:3000 through ngrok?

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way, assuming you are fine with having Cloudflare only act as DNS:

1. Configure ngrok to serve the correct TLS certificate.  In ngrok for your domain `app.example.com`, select the "Automated TLS certificates" option, which means ngrok will provision one for you.
2. In Cloudflare, "[grey cloud the DNS record](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/360019093151#h_70577325041543271574371)" so that traffic is no longer proxied through Cloudflare before it is proxied through ngrok.  Now it will only be proxied through ngrok before being forwarded to your local server.
3. Start your ngrok tunnel.  Assuming your local server is not configured to terminate TLS, you can run something like `ngrok http --bind-tls=true --hostname=app.example.com 3000` to start a HTTPS only tunnel endpoint.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking ngrok tunnel solution proposed and I also found a way you can do an Argo Tunnel through cloudflare directly. This can be another approach to the problem. https://developers.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-one/tutorials/share-new-site

Answer (score 1):

I didn't answer your question. I just want to share, that we can make localhost on our computer accessible through our own domain using cloudflare tunneling.

https://developers.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-one/connections/connect-apps/install-and-setup/tunnel-guide/

Comment: Unfortunately, your answer is not relevant to the question.

Comment: Please, check this link https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead

Comment: Okay, I'm not going to answer any more questions here. This is my first and last answer here.
Thank you @GregoireCattan.

Comment: It is still a useful answer for solo developers who are always looking to simplify their workflow and don't have the overhead or beauracracy of a tech company to hurdle through to simply use a tunnel from the same provider of the DNS they are already using.

StackO serves people who are looking for ANY answer, not just a direct answer IMHO. I know indirect answers can get unruly, but this is a case where some nuance is acceptable, especially with a direct answer already provided. Not everyone has the privilege of paying for ngrok — CF only charges for volume which is tiny for a solo dev.